# Event throttling / queuing - Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, silverlight-5.0

I am looking to implement some throttling behavior into one of my viewmodels.  It's a silverlight application, however I don't think that's particularly important.

Consider a class with three properties:

- Property1
- Property2
- Property3

Whenever one of these properties is updated, a refresh is neccessary.

```
private void Refresh()
{
    //Call out to the server, do something when it comes back
}
```

My goals are as follows:

- If a Refresh is in progress, we should ideally cancel the call to the server, and issue a new request
- If a property is changed, we should leave some small window of time (perhaps 0.1 seconds) where we wait for additional changes.  This way, if multiple properties are changed rapidly (for example, programmatically) we don't spam the server with requests.  It's OK for that 0.1 second window to reset on each change, but not required.

If it matters, I am using a ChannelFactory implementation for the server call.

What kind of patterns can I use to accomplish this?  Is this something reactive extensions can help me with?

**Edit:**

Marking Paul's answer as correct.  While ReactiveUI doesn't currently work against silverlight5, it clearly outlines the approach / composition steps to solving the problem using Rx.

Comment: Rx definitely supports this, see http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc29 - about cancelling it - take a look at CancellationToken from Tasks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you would do this with ReactiveUI:

```
IObservable<TheData> FetchNewData() 
{
    // TODO: Implement me
}

this.WhenAny(x => x.Property1, x => x.Property2, x => x.Property3, (x,y,z) => Unit.Default)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), RxApp.DeferredScheduler)
    .Select(x => FetchNewData())
    .Switch()    // We only care about the req corresp. to latest values of Prop1-3
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Data);
```

**Update:** Here's how to guarantee that there is only one running at a time, with the caveat that you may get out-of-order results.

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Property1, x => x.Property2, x => x.Property3, (x,y,z) => Unit.Default)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), RxApp.DeferredScheduler)
    .Select(_ => Observable.Defer(() => FetchNewData()))
    .Merge(1)
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Data);
```

The behavior you describe, would actually be perhaps not desireable, since if the properties keep changing, you'll end up with a queue of old requests to issue - you could optimize this if you made something like a "BufferingSwitch()" operator that didn't return its results until it was sure there were no changes - that'd actually be cool to write.

Moral of the story, Async Is Complicated™ :)

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I need at first glance.  Is this valid for silverlight?  I can't find the WhenAny extension method to give this a try.

Comment: @ShaunRowan: That extension is from ReactiveUI (http://www.reactiveui.net). Previous versions (v2) support Silverlight. The current version (v3) does not. Especially if you are doing MVVM, this is a really great library.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!  For some reason my brain just swapped out "ReactiveUI" with "reactive extensions".  (I wasn't aware of the library.)

Comment: @ShaunRowan The current version *will* support SL5 once I get off my ass and fix it

Comment: Very interesting library.  What if, instead of throttling by time, i wanted to throttle such that FetchNewData() would only be running 1 time concurrently?  Any ideas on something like that?

Comment: @ShaunRowan This gets a bit trickier - you can certainly limit FetchNewData to one concurrent request, but then you may get requests out of order. I've shown how to do it above

Comment: BufferingSwitch concept sounds promising.  I have a lot to learn about observables/Rx.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'may get requests out of order'?  The FetchNewData method actually uses the properties so it should have the latest 'parameters' whenever it makes the call.

Comment: And yes, async is complicated :)